# how can i use transparencykey inside other form

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

Explanation:

i got 2 forms (`form1`,`form2`),

`form1` backgroundImage = GetImage("http://us.cdn2.123rf.com/168nwm/exe2k/exe2k1210/exe2k121000019/15806640-chess-board-background-photo.jpg")

```
######################################
```

`form2` backcolor = `black`
`form2` transparencykey  = `black`

```
######################################
```

Note:
form2 is smaller than form1

now lets insert form2 into form1:

```
form2.TopLevel = false
form2.Show()
form1.controls.add(form2)
```

The result should be:

(b=black)(w=white)

```
--------------------
form1        - [] X
--------------------
|B|W|B|W|B|W|B|W|B|W
--------------------
form2        - [] X
--------------------
|B|W|B|W|B|W|B|W|B|W
|B|W|B|W|B|W|B|W|B|W
|B|W|B|W|B|W|B|W|B|W
--------------------
|B|W|B|W|B|W|B|W|B|W
--------------------
```

But the result is:

(b=BLACK)(w=white)

```
--------------------
form1        - [] X
--------------------
|B|W|B|W|B|W|B|W|B|W
--------------------
form2        - [] X
--------------------
|B|B|B|B|B|B|B|B|B|B
|B|B|B|B|B|B|B|B|B|B
|B|B|B|B|B|B|B|B|B|B
--------------------
|B|W|B|W|B|W|B|W|B|W
--------------------
```

form2 backcolor = black.
but form2 transparencykey = black too.
It means that i can't use transparencykey/opacity inside form control.
the only thing i can do is place form2 on form1.panel1:

```
form2.show()
//form2 is not in form 1
waitUntilFormShown(form2)
do while true
form2.location = form1.panel1.location
application.doEvents()
system.thrading.thread.sleep(1)
loop
```

(I did not checked the code)

This is not the right way to solve it.
(When Minimize/Maximize/Resize on form1 will be necessary to call Minimize/Maximize/Resize of form2 and there are more reasons why i do not do it).
The last things that left to ask is:how can i fix it? or why its happening?...
Note:this "bug" does not apply on picturebox control.(This is the reason that made me ask from the beginning).

Comment: What exactly want to do? Should it show the back screen of form1 through form2? or show form1 client area through form1?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the form2 opacity property to 0 and leave transparency key at default value and set the back color to be same as form1

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.TopLevel = false;
frm.BackColor = Form1.BackColor;
frm.Opacity = 0;
frm.Show();
Form1.Controls.Add(frm);
```

Comment: i tried it, still the same (form2.opacity = 0,form2.TopLevel = false,me.backcolor=red,me.controls.add(form2)) Edit: if i will set form2 backcolor as form1.backcolor i dont need to use opacity, and in my case i'm using images and not colors.(Explanation by color is much more understandable)

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.  If you are trying to hide form2, just send it back behind a panel on form1,  Otherwise the opacity settings and transparency key are used to provide appearance of "floating controls".

Comment: read my question again and then you will understand what i'm trying to do.(i changed the question)